# Attempting to take the average of a certain portion of beginning and end of array

Tags: c, arrays, compression

The following problem is being run on a PLC completely written in C. This function is part of a library that I have attempted to add.

I have a float array of data of arbitrary length. The following code is triggered when the array length is >= 25 entries. This function is supposed to determine the first and last x percent of entries (i.e. 33% of an array of 99 would be the first and last 33 entries). The first and last portions are then averaged and compressed into two halves (or half +/- 1 in the case of odd input arrays). The final output is a combination of these two arrays.

For this purpose, I am trying to make a function of this form:

```
plcbit arrayCompressFloatExtremities(float* arrayToCopyResultTo,
        float* arrayToDecrease, unsigned long numberOfDesiredElements,
        unsigned long numberOfElementsInOriginal, float inclusionZonePercent)
```

where

- `float* arrayToCopyResultTo` is my target array after the function finishes
- `float* arrayToDecrease` is the input array pointer
- `unsigned long numberofDesiredElements` is the length of the output array, should be 25
- `unsigned long numberofElementsInOriginal` is the length of the original array, >=25
- `float inclusionZonePercent` is the percentage of the front and back end of the array I want to compress. E.g. a value input of .25 will compress the first 25% and last 25% of the entries into an array 25 entries in length

So far, it seems that the code works to a point.  The `usedInterval` value appears to be dividing by zero in my debugger, however, and I'm not certain why. Regardless, I am not confident I set this up right.

```
/* compresses and compies the array while neglecting a certain percentage of the board */
plcbit arrayCompressFloatExtremities(float* arrayToCopyResultTo,
        float* arrayToDecrease, unsigned long numberOfDesiredElements,
        unsigned long numberOfElementsInOriginal, float inclusionZonePercent) {
    int usedInterval = 0, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, numberOfElementsLeft = 0;
    double temp = 0;
    float zone = 0;

    if ((numberOfElementsInOriginal == 0) || (numberOfDesiredElements == 0)) return 0;

    // determine zone size
    numberOfElementsInOriginal = sizeof(arrayToDecrease);
    numberOfElementsLeft = numberOfElementsInOriginal * inclusionZonePercent;

    // compress zone A into first half of output array using modulo operator
    // for odd number arrays

    for (i = 0;
            i < ((numberOfDesiredElements - (numberOfDesiredElements % 2)) / 2);
            i++) // i starts at 0 for the beginning part of the board and continues until the halfway point or halfway - 1
    {
        usedInterval = numberOfElementsLeft /
                (((numberOfDesiredElements - (numberOfDesiredElements % 2)) / 2) - i); 
        temp = 0;
        for (j = 0;
                j < (usedInterval + numberOfElementsInOriginal - numberOfElementsLeft);
                j++) {
            temp += arrayToDecrease[j];
        }

        arrayToCopyResultTo[i] = temp / (float) usedInterval;

        numberOfElementsLeft -= usedInterval;
    }
    // compress zone B
    numberOfElementsLeft = numberOfElementsInOriginal * inclusionZonePercent;   
    for (i = (numberOfElementsInOriginal - numberOfElementsLeft);
            i < (numberOfDesiredElements + (numberOfDesiredElements % 2));
            i++) // i starts at the end of the board minus the appropriate percentile and fills array with half of desired point or halfwat + 1
    {
        usedInterval = numberOfElementsLeft /
                (((numberOfDesiredElements + (numberOfDesiredElements % 2)) / 2) - i);
        temp = 0;
        for (j = (numberOfElementsInOriginal - numberOfElementsLeft);
                j < (usedInterval + numberOfElementsInOriginal - numberOfElementsLeft);
                j++) {
            temp += arrayToDecrease[j];
        }

        arrayToCopyResultTo[i] = temp / (float)usedInterval;

        numberOfElementsLeft -= usedInterval;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I'm hoping that this algorithm will be able to take the beginning percentile of the array and the end, compress the values (through averaging entries), and output the values in an array while ignoring the middle values of the array.

Comment: In what sense is 33% of 99 equal to 3?  Do you mean 33?

Comment: Literally just edited that, but yes it was a typo

Comment: You are passing `numberOfElementsInOriginal` as a parameter, which is fine, then you are replacing the passed value via `numberOfElementsInOriginal = sizeof(arrayToDecrease);`, which is completely wrong (it gives you the size of a pointer, which is completely unrelated to the number of elements in the array).

Comment: As for whether you've "set this up right", I see several *stylistic* issues, but to evaluate the correctness of the code I would need a clear specification of what it means to "average and compress" the leading and trailing sub-arrays.  I cannot rely for that on the code itself, since its correctness is in question.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comments, you have a definite error in

```
numberOfElementsInOriginal = sizeof(arrayToDecrease);
```

because `sizeof(arrayToDecrease)` gives you the size of a pointer, in bytes, which is not in any way related to the number of elements in the array (in)to which the pointer points.  Since `numberOfElementsInOriginal` is a function parameter, I'm inclined to guess that this is an unwanted leftover from a previous version of the function, such that it can simply be removed.

As far as style and approach go, it appears that you use exactly the same approach for the lead half of the destination array as for the trailing half.  If that's indeed what you want, then

- your code could be both shortened and simplified by factoring that out to a separate function

that you call twice.  Additionally, although its very rare for me to say this in a SO answer,

- your variable names are too long.

Those long names are pretty clear, but having so many variable names of such great length makes your code *harder* to read and understand, not easier, especially when several of them are similar to each other.  You can create shorter names that are still plenty descriptive by starting with shorter phrases, omitting prepositions, using abbreviations (especially conventional ones), and even just expressing the idea differently.  For example,

```
plcbit arrayCompressFloatExtremities(float *dest,
        float *src, unsigned long dest_len,
        unsigned long src_len, float inclusion_fraction)
```

I've also switched to snake_style instead of camelStyle there.  The former is more common in C code and I prefer it in that context, but the latter is ok, too.

As for the actual averaging, if you have trouble following the code enough to be confident of its correctness then correctness is not its deepest problem.  I don't know about you, but even knowing (I think) what you're trying to do, it is very difficult for me to analyze your code to validate it.  In addition to the issues I already mentioned, this problem arises in part from use of

- complex inline expressions

and it is especially egregious that

- such expressions are *duplicated*, and
- some are *needlessly* complex.

Take this several-times-repeated expression in particular:

```
numberOfDesiredElements - (numberOfDesiredElements % 2)) / 2
```

Given that `numberOnumberOfDesiredElements` has an unsigned integer type, that expression will *always* evaluate to the same result as just

```
numberOfDesiredElements / 2
```

, which is much clearer and less than half the length.  Even making that substitution doesn't clear up the code enough for me to be confident about whether it is right, however.

Consider this alternative, in the form of a function that you could call once for each half:

```
/*
 * Partitions the source array evenly into dest_len bins, and records the average
 * of the elements in each bin in the corresponding element of the destination
 * array.  When dest_len does not evenly divide src_len, each of the src_len % dest_len
 * initial bins is one element longer than the trailing bins.
 *
 * dest:     a pointer to the array wherein the results are to be stored
 * dest_len: the number of leading elements of dest to fill; must not exceed src_len
 * src:      a pointer to the array containing the source elements
 * src_len:  the number of initial elements of src to process
 */
void compress_array(float *dest, size_t dest_len, float *src, size_t src_len) {
    // This implementation depends on these assumptions to be true:
    assert(0 < dest_len && dest_len <= src_len && dest_len <= ULONG_MAX / 2 + 1);

    size_t base_bin_size = src_len / dest_len;
    size_t num_extras = src_len % dest_len;

    // Iterate over the bins
    for (size_t dest_inx = 0; dest_inx < dest_len; dest_inx++) {
        // This is a concise (but perhaps too clever) way of distributing
        // the left-over source elements to bins, one element to each bin
        // until they are used up.  It depends on the fact that relational
        // expressions evaluate to either 0 or 1, and on the fact that
        // unsigned arithmetic wraps around:
        unsigned long bin_size = base_bin_size + (--num_extras < dest_len);

        // Average the elements in this bin
        float temp = 0;
        for (size_t bin_inx = 0; bin_inx < bin_size; bin_inx++) {
            // keeps track of our position in the source array by incrementing src
            temp += *(src++);
        }

        dest[dest_inx] = temp / bin_size;
    }
}
```

To me, that's simple and clear, and it clearly does the job it is documented to do.  (And note: what it does is well and clearly documented.)  I'm not certain that what that function is documented to do is exactly what you need such a function to do, but the point is really to demonstrate some ways to write clearer, more maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and helpful response John. I will take this example here and apply the percentile discrimination I mentioned earlier. The stylistic errors are definitely true, especially when it comes to variable names, but I am doing all of my work on older systems and using the convention made by others before me in order to keep things consistent.